# How to edit/delete table by individual row using a modal?

Tags: php, mysql, html, mysqli

I have a table where I want the user to be able to edit information or delete entire row. 
The data is retrieved from 3 tables in my database.

my tables:

**table 1:**

```
| ID | name | dancer name | dance name1 | comp_num1 | dance score1| etc|

| 1 |....rob....|.......jen......... | ...dance A...... | .........23........|......... 44........|etc|

| 2 |....rob....|.......larry....... | ...dance B...... | .........50........|......... 60........|etc|

| 3 |....rob....|.......jen......... | ...dance C...... | .........14........|........344........|etc|
```

**table 2**

```
| ID | name | dancer name | dance name2 | comp_num2 | dance score2| etc|

| 1 |....rob....|.......jen......... | ...dance D...... | .........33........|......... 94........|etc|

| 2 |....rob....|.......larry....... | ...dance E...... | .........52........|......... 60........|etc|

| 3 |....rob....|.......jen......... | ...dance F...... | .........10........|........244........|etc|
```

**table 3**

```
| ID | name | dancer name | dance name3 | comp_num3 | dance score3| etc|

| 1 |....rob....|.......jen......... | ...dance G...... | .........13........|......... 39........|etc|

| 2 |....rob....|.......larry....... | ...dance H...... | .........22........|......... 70........|etc|

| 3 |....rob....|.......jen......... | ...dance I...... | .........1........|........230........|etc|
```

To edit information they will click on the green icon button that will show a pop-up modal.

[image: table]

The modal has 2 tabs. One for displaying some details and the other tab is an update form.

[image: modal]

the details tab displays like this:

Dancer name: competition name - competition level - placement

Judge Name: Judge's name

Judge Comments: Judge's comments

The issue that I am having is that the information in the modal pulled from the database is the same for every button pressed. But it should only get the information from the row of the button.

In the photos you will notice I only have three buttons. That's because I was only doing table 1 first. So from table one, all 3 dancers (jen, larry, and jen) are having the same details as larry when clicking on the action button.

I also need to be able to update each line by the row as well. I think I need to pass the id somehow, but I am not sure how to go about this.

```
 <!--TABLES-->

        <div id="table" class="table-responsive-sm">
            <table id="History" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive-sm table-hover" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%">  
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th id="firstName" style="width: 10%">First <br> Name</th>
                        <th id="competition" >Competition <br> Name</th>
                        <th id="level">Competition Level</th>
                        <th id="danceName">Dance Name</th>
                        <th id="numComp" style="width: 10%">Number of Competitors</th>
                        <th id="placement" style="width: 10%">Dancer's Placement</th>
                        <th id="score">Dancer's Score</th>
                        <th id="firstPlace">1st Place Score</th>
                        <th id="action" style="width: 10%" data-feild="operate" data-events="operateEvents" data-formatter="operateFormatter">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>

                    <!-- The modal is only updating the last loop. So I need to do something similar to what I did with the dancer dropdown button. -->

                    <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT `id`, `dancer_name`, `comp_entered`, `competition_level1`, `dance_name1`, `number_competitors1`, `dancer_placement1`, `dancer_score1`, `firstpl_score1`, `2ndpl_score1`, `3rdpl_score1`, `judge_name1`, `judge_comment1` FROM `mark_cards1` WHERE name = '$name'";
                    $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql); 
                    $markcard = 'id';
                    //if($res==FALSE){
                    //die('there was an error running query [' . $con->error . ']');
                    //  }

                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
                        echo '
                        <tr>
                        <td>'.$row["dancer_name"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["comp_entered"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["competition_level1"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["dance_name1"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["number_competitors1"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["dancer_placement1"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["dancer_score1"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["firstpl_score1"].'</td>
                        <td>
                        <!--MODAL-->
                        <div class="modal fade" id="modalLRForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog cascading-modal" role="document">

                        <!--MODAL Content-->
                                <div class="modal-content">

                        <!--Modal cascading tabs-->
                                    <div class="modal-c-tabs">
                                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-2 light-blue darken-3" role="tablist">
                                            <li class="nav-item">
                                                <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#panel7" role="tab">Details</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="nav-item">
                                                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#panel8" role="tab">Edit</a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>

                        <!-- Tab Panels  -->
                                        <div class="tab-content">

                            <!--PANEL 1 -->
                                            <div class="tab-pane fade in show active" id="panel7" role="tabpanel">

                                <!--Body-->
                                                <div class="modal-body mb-1">
                                                    <b>'.$row["dancer_name"].'</b>: '.$row["comp_entered"].' - '.$row["competition_level1"].' - '.$row["dancer_placement1"].' 
                                                    <br>
                                                    <b>Judge:</b> '.$row["judge_name1"].'
                                                    <br>
                                                    <b>Comments:</b> '.$row["judge_comment1"].'
                                                </div>                                    
                                <!--Footer-->
                                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info waves-effect ml-auto" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>     

                            <!--Panel 2-->
                                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="panel8" role="tabpanel">

                                <!--Body-->
                                                <div class="modal-body">
                                                    <form id="updateForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal" name="tcol" action="edit_comp.php>" role="form" data-toggle="validator">
                                                        <div class="md-form form-sm mb-5">
                                                            <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="modalLRInput12">Dancer Name</label>
                                                            <select class="form-control dancebox" id="dancer" name="dancer"><option>'.$data["dancer_name"].'</option>;}
                                                            </select>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="md-form form-sm mb-5">
                                                            <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="modalLRInput12">Region</label>

                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="md-form form-sm mb-5">
                                                            <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="modalLRInput12">Competition Name</label>
                                                            <select class="form-control compbox" id="compEntered" name="compEntered">
                                                            <option value="base">Please choose a Region</option>
                                                            </select>
                                                        </div>


                                                        <div class="md-form form-sm mb-5">
                                                            <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="modalLRInput12">Competition Level</label>
                                                            <select class="form-control levelbox" id="level" name="level">
                                                                <option>Beginner</option>
                                                                <option>Advanced Beginner</option>
                                                                <option>Novice</option>
                                                                <option>Prize Winner</option>
                                                                <option>Prelim</option>
                                                                <option>Open Champion</option>
                                                            </select>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="md-form form-sm mb-5">
                                                            <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="modalLRInput12">Dance Name</label>
                                                            <select class="form-control" id="danceName" name="danceName">
                                                            <option>Reel</option>
                                                            <option>Light Jig</option>
                                                            <option>Slip Jig</option>
                                                            <option>Hornpipe</option>
                                                            </select>
                                                        </div>



                                                        <div class="md-form form-sm mb-5">
                                                            <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="modalLRInput12">Number of Competitiors</label>
                                                            <input id="competitior" type="text" name="competitor" class="form-control competitors" placeholder="Enter total competitors">
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="md-form form-sm mb-5">
                                                            <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="modalLRInput12">Dancer Placement</label>
                                                            <select class="form-control" id="placement" name="placement">
                                                            <option>1st place</option>
                                                            <option>2nd place</option>
                                                            <option>3rd place</option>
                                                            <option>4th place</option>
                                                            </select>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="md-form form-sm mb-5">
                                                            <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="modalLRInput12">Dancer Score</label>
                                                            <input id="danceScore" type="text" name="danceScore" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter score ">
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="md-form form-sm mb-5">
                                                            <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="modalLRInput12">1st Place Score</label>
                                                            <input id="firstScore" type="text" name="firstScore" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter first place score ">
                                                        </div>





                                                        <div class="text-center form-sm mt-2">
                                                            <button class="btn btn-info">Update</button>
                                                            <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete comp</button>
                                                        </div> 
                                                    </form>
                                                </div>                                    
                                <!--Footer-->
                                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info waves-effect ml-auto" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                            <!--END Panel 2-->
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <!--END Content-->
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="text-center">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary details-btn" style="background:#9ACB00" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalLRForm" data-id=""><i class="fas fa-eye fa-lg" data-fa-transform="shrink-1 up-5 left-9 "></i></button>
                        </div>


                                <!--modal end --></td>
                        </tr> 
                        ';  
                    }
                    $sql2 = "SELECT `dancer_name`,`comp_entered`,`competition_level1`, `dance_name2`, `number_competitors2`, `dancer_placement2`, `dancer_score2`, `firstpl_score2`, `2ndpl_score2`, `3rdpl_score2`, `judge_name2`, `judge_comment2` FROM `mark_cards2` WHERE name = '$name'";
                    $res2 = mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
                    //if($res==FALSE){
                    //die('there was an error running query [' . $con->error . ']');
                    //  }

                    while($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($res2)){
                        echo '
                        <tr>
                        <td>'.$row2["dancer_name"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row2["copm_entered"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row2["competition_level1"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row2["dance_name2"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row2["number_competitors2"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row2["dancer_placement2"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row2["dancer_score2"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row2["firstpl_score2"].'</td>
                        <td></td>
                        </tr> 
                        ';  
                    }

                    $sql3 = "SELECT `dancer_name`,`comp_entered`,`competition_level1`, `dance_name3`, `number_competitors3`, `dancer_placement3`, `dancer_score3`, `firstpl_score3`, `2ndpl_score3`, `3rdpl_score3`, `judge_name3`, `judge_comment3` FROM `mark_cards3` WHERE name = '$name'";
                    $res3 = mysqli_query($con,$sql3); 

                    //if($res==FALSE){
                    //die('there was an error running query [' . $con->error . ']');
                    //  }

                    while($row3=mysqli_fetch_array($res3)){
                        echo '
                        <tr>
                        <td>'.$row3["dancer_name"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row3["comp_entered"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row3["competition_level1"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row3["dance_name3"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row3["number_competitors3"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row3["dancer_placement3"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row3["dancer_score3"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row3["firstpl_score3"].'</td>
                        <td>  </td>
                        </tr> 
                        ';
                    }
                    ?>

                </tbody>


            </table>
```

Comment: `id="modalLRForm" `  You are giving every modal the same ID.  Every HTML element must have a unique ID (especially if you want to be able to reference them by ID using jQuery, which you are doing by having `data-target="#modalLRForm"`).  Personally, I'd probably request the modal data via ajax when the button is clicked, and re-use the same modal, instead of pre-loading it all when you might not need it.

Comment: I am only using one modal and that modal has id="modalLRForm". The modal is in a while loop along with all of the other table data. So, I think I need to somehow get the modal to retrieve the id of each row. But I'm racking my brain on how to do this.

Comment: You are creating the modal _within_ your loop.  This means that you do not have one, but one _per result row_.  However, since you give each one the same ID, and then use that ID to determine the target of your click, only the first one will ever be opened.  Like I said, instead of populating the data into the modal beforehand, I would use ajax to fetch that on click of the Edit button, and _then_ populate the modal, which you would have created just once, _outside_ of the loop.

Comment: Can this be done without using ajax?